# GEE doesn't name bands on toBands() with Landsat-8

Tags: google-earth-engine

**ee.ImageCollection.toBands**

> Converts a collection to a single multi-band image containing all of
> the bands of every image in the collection. Output bands are named by
> prefixing the existing band names with the image id from which it came
> (e.g.: 'image1_band1')

And this seems to work with Sentinel images, but on Landsat it names the bands "band_1", "band_2" etc...

Here's my code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/27658f07ca7c59f6aa96daa60b9f6004

```
var d1 = '2020-01-01';
var d2 = '2020-05-01';
var g = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[11.674564691130675, 51.253499795452036],
          [11.674564691130675, 51.19845826683864],
          [11.762455316130675, 51.19845826683864],
          [11.762455316130675, 51.253499795452036]]], null, false);
          
var renameToDOY_NDVI = function(image){
  var doy = image.date().getRelative('day', 'year');
  var dt = image.date().format("YYYY_MM_dd");
  return image.select('NDVI').rename(dt.cat('_').cat(ee.Number(doy).format('%03d')));
};

var addNDVI_L8 = function(image){
  var NDVI = image.normalizedDifference(['SR_B5', 'SR_B4']).rename('NDVI')
  return image.addBands(NDVI);
};

function maskL8sr(image) {
  var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3);
  var cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5);
  var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL');
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
                  .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}

var L8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
  .filterDate(d1, d2)
  .filterBounds(g).map(maskL8sr);
  
var L8_NDVI = L8.map(addNDVI_L8);

print(L8_NDVI.select(['NDVI']).map(renameToDOY_NDVI).first())
// the id of first image is LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2/LC08_193024_20200118
// the band name of first image is 2020_01_18_017

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: L8_NDVI.select(['NDVI']).map(renameToDOY_NDVI).toBands(),
  description: 'L8_NDVI_ALL',
  region: g,
  scale: 30,
  folder: 'L8',
  maxPixels: 1e13,
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
  formatOptions: {
    cloudOptimized: true
  }
});
// the band name of first image after export is "Band_1".
```

Am I doing something wrong? How to export it with image ids and proper band names? I want to export multiple years at once, not only one.

On L8 (tried both below, and the code that I have given) names are like this:

[image]

On S2 (only DOY and cloud cover added) names are like this:

[image]

On S1 (only DOY added) names are like this:

[image]

PS. These screens are from ArcMap Desktop 10.8.1, but GDAL can also read the band names.

Answer (score -1):

GeoTIFF doesn't have an actual standard for band names, so the output bands are "unnamed" and whatever you're reading them with is  assigning the names "band_1", etc.

There's currently no way to include the band names in the file.

Comment: not really true... I gave a cite from documentation... it names the bands with image id as a prefix when doing exactly the same operation on Sentinel-1 or Sentinel-2 data, so the name of similar script for every band is IMAGE_ID_DATE_DOY for every image exported that way

Comment: check my edit with real life examples